# How to access the MTD char device Read/Write details?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, flash-memory, archlinux-arm

I want to know the amount of bytes Read/Write on MTD char device. What is the way to get it?

It would be OK either via C or terminal.

- I am mounting the mtd device as  embedded device.
- mtd partitions are done in the SPI flash and it's not mounted. We directly using the `/dev/mtdN` for `read/write`.

Comment: How you want to know via c program or just check via terminal?

Comment: I need the way to find the amount of bytes Write/Read on MTD char device. It ok with either via C or terminal. Please suggest in both the ways.

Comment: Are you mounting the mtd device as flash dir in your embedded device?

Comment: embedded device, mtd partitions are done in the SPI flash and it's not mounted. We directly using the /dev/mtdN for read/write.

Comment: I want to the know the amount that has been read/written using MTD char device since the beginning

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  If I write a byte to the MTD then re-write the _same_ byte, is that one byte or two?  Are you trying to determine used space or number of accesses?  The former is a matter of definition of "used" and format/data structure, and I doubt the latter is intrinsically accounted.  Also "since the beginning" of what - since power-up or since the beginning of time?  And finally... why?

Comment: Here the clear details, hope you aware of how 'iostat' works on block device. As similar to the 'iostat', need to get the Read/Write information for CHAR device (i.e /dev/mtdN) since of the power-up of the system.
for example:
User writes 10 bytes by 5 time in same location(like re-writing), i expected the output of this trace is 50Bytes. Because, 5 times the write command send to the flash device for each 10Bytes.

Comment: Is there any way to trace MTD as char device?